# Changing the font size of the Angular Material Select Panel?

Tags: html, css, angular, sass, angular-material

We can change the general panel css style using `panelClass`.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" panelClass="select-style">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping"
      >{{topping}}</mat-option
    >
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And the style:

```
.select-style {
  font-size: 2px !important;
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  border: 1px solid gray !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 12px !important;
  height: 10rem;
}
```

[This is a stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y6mxsu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.scss,src%2Fapp%2Fselect-custom-trigger-example.ts,src%2Findex.html).

All the settings are taking effect except for the `font-size`.  It does not change.  Any ideas on how to change the font size for the panel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.select-style {
  border-radius: 20px !important;
  border: 1px solid gray !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: 12px !important;
  height: 10rem;
}
.select-style mat-option{
  font-size: 8px !important;
}
```

---

**Reason**: The font-size is being set on the `mat-option` inside `.select-style` as

```
<mat-option role="option" 
 class="mat-mdc-option mat-mdc-focus-indicator mdc-list-item..."...>...<mat-option>
```

css

```
.mat-mdc-option {
    /*...*/
    font-size: var(--mdc-typography-body1-font-size, 16px);
    /*...*/
}
```

We have to override the `mat-option` `font-size` set.